# android how to find angle(0->360) towards destination from current user location

Tags: android, location, direction, bearing

I have the current longitude and latitude of the user and a destination (just a static location). How can I find the direction `angle(0->360)` between the current user's location and the destination?

I'm currently using `currentLocation.bearingTo(destination)` as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo(android.location.Location)) but I'm not able to find the correct angle.

Comment: What is your current input and output of that function?

Comment: Improved wording and grammar

Answer (score 3):

finally I got solution for this and I am sharing here because may it help others.

```
private double bearing(double startLat, double startLng, double endLat, double endLng){
        double longitude1 = startLng;
        double longitude2 = endLng;
        double latitude1 = Math.toRadians(startLat);
        double latitude2 = Math.toRadians(endLat);
        double longDiff= Math.toRadians(longitude2-longitude1);
        double y= Math.sin(longDiff)*Math.cos(latitude2);
        double x=Math.cos(latitude1)*Math.sin(latitude2)-Math.sin(latitude1)*Math.cos(latitude2)*Math.cos(longDiff);
        return (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x))+360)%360;
    }
```

if method is not returning desired value then you must check your longitude and latitude values.
note this method return value between 0->360 degree.